# Error while installing cassandra

Tags: connection, cassandra

I tried to install **cassandra** many time by removing it,
but it always  gives this error:

```
$ cqlsh

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Comment: how did you install it - via packages, from tarball? what is in the logs, etc.?

Comment: by using sudo apt get install cassendra

Comment: what is in the `/var/log/cassandra/system.log`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with your hostname after cqlsh followed by the port number.

```
cqlsh <hostname> <9042>
```

or

```
cqlsh <hostname>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check cassandra is up with this command:

```
nodestool status
```

You can see  errors   in the following log file: `/var/log/cassandara/debug.log`